# Equal contribution for second and third authors

Tags: authorship, author-order

We are six co-authors in an applied CS paper (AI). This paper has a "strong" first author who worked on this project for years. Two student authors (let's call them Alice and Bob) contributed to the paper, and the other co-authors are seniors.

Since Alice and Bob have roughly the same contribution, we use a lexicographic tiebreaker, and placed Alice before Bob. While Alice is (unsurprisingly) happy with this solution, it bothers Bob.

I thought of several solutions:

1. We stay with the lexicographic tiebreaker between Alice and Bob.
2. Flip a coin to determine the order.
3. Put an asterisk suggesting equal contribution to the second and third authors.
4. Other creative solutions?

My question is about option 3. I've yet to encounter an "equal contribution" remark that is not about the first author. Since there is a sole first author, is it reasonable to remark that the second and third have equal contribution? Any other thoughts?

Comment: Can you put in something like an acknowledgement section: _contributions_. Try to write something that pleases all or displeases few.

Comment: Why not just switch Alice and Bob? If Alice doesn't care, but Bob does, why not place him before Alice?

Comment: #3 is a thing in biology-related fields and has been for a while. It's not nearly as common as co-first authorship though.

Comment: @Buffy I guess this is even more cumbersome.

Comment: @user111388 Alice does care, edited.

Comment: @CJR Thanks for the feedback. Can you add a link to demonstrate how it's done?

Comment: I hate to suggest the sensible solution generally used in theoretical CS and in pure mathematics. Strict alphabetical listing. Or dueling pistols on the village green at dawn. That used to be the way.

Comment: My prof told about his advisor's special method: He would give Bob a stern talking to (or Alice, it doesn't matter) that this is bad behaviour and if it continues, he wouldn't be so sure if he let Bob graduate. this usually kept the students quiet. But I don't recommend it anymore as Buffy recommends the Pistol duel;)

Comment: @omerbp [Nature's author guide](https://www.nature.com/nature/for-authors/formatting-guide) just says `two or more co-authors are equal in status` and I'm sure I've seen recent papers where that's been applied to the second (or corresponding) authors. Mostly it gets applied to first authorship just because people don't often fight over second vs third as much.

Comment: @omerbp In my field (computer vision), it's absolutely normal to indicate that several authors other than the first have made an equal contribution. You just put a * next to their names and add a footnote. For example: http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2017/papers/Cavallari_On-The-Fly_Adaptation_of_CVPR_2017_paper.pdf

Comment: @CJR It's not always done because people were fighting over it either, for what it's worth - it's considered normal to do it just to reflect the actual contributions people made, rather than because anyone was actually annoyed/complaining about it.

Comment: My advice would be that Alice and Bob go back to doing something useful.  The additional value of being second author instead of third is minuscule.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I'm not sure I would direct all of my fire at Alice and Bob in this scenario to be honest. It hardly seems fair to (i) set up an incentive structure that focuses on silly things like author order, (ii) penalise the careers of people who ignore that, and (iii) blame people who take it into account. In an ideal world, researchers would focus only on the topic at hand and not on credit - but senior academics have a part to play in setting up the incentive structure to encourage that. People care about nonsense like this only because they're incentivised to care about it.

Comment: @Buffy Are there lots of people called Professor Aardvark in theoretical CS and pure maths by any chance? :)

Comment: @StuartGolodetz, no, I think I'm the only one.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question nr. 4 ("Other creative solutions?"):

Making explicit each contributor's role based on [CRediT (Contributor Roles Taxonomy)](https://casrai.org/credit/) may solve some issues.

Many publishers already support the integration of such formalized contributor statements.

Answer (score 2):

I have been second and third author on several AI papers in recent years. The distinction between the two is minimal. There is no impact on how important second- or third-author papers are on one's further career. The impact of first-author or last-author papers may be different, but the other positions in the author list are relatively unimportant.

I would just flip a coin, in the presence of both Alice and Bob. If the loser of the coin toss has a problem with the outcome, I would never write a paper with this person again, because life is too short to bother with such trivialities.

Answer (score 0):

Option3 is fine.
Take a look at https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.04088.pdf

Comment: Hi and welcome to Academia SE. Could you please expand on your answer? Something done in an arXiv submission may not be accepted in a regular submission or not so universally recognized.